# Open all Vim tabs for a Rails workflow automagically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, vim

I'm working on PHP, Python and Rails projects now and would like to get to work quicker each time I switch projects.

I have found some Guake or ABC-terminal automation scripts to load up my different terminals with certain commands (`rails server --debugger`, `vim ~/railsapp`, `cd ~/railsapp`, etc).

**Q.** What is the launch command to make one of those terminals open Vim with multiple tabs at pre-determined directories or files?

Comment: You might also find that tmux can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:help mksession`.

Basically you setup a workspace manually: this buffer in that split, these splits in that tab… and do `:mksession /path/to/mysession.vim`. After that you can start Vim with `$ vim -S /path/to/mysession.vim` and see Vim rebuild your workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you haven't already, add [NerdTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) plugin to your vim config. This will enable you to manage any Rails project in better way. `vim ~/rails_app` will give you directory structure of project and then you can manage the tabs. 
And as romainl already mentioned, mksession can help you to setup workspaces.